# QNetworkReply error signal not detected when connection is lost

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I'm downloading files from a remote server with Qt5.5 and everything works fine but I can't detect when a QNetworkReply returns an error.
In fact, I am trying to check the case if the user is downloading a file and suddenly, he loses his Internet connection (because why not :-) ). To do that, I start a download and unplug my Ethernet cable a few seconds after.

Is the signal `QNetworkReply::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)` emitted in this case? If yes, why am I not entering my slot in my code below?

```
void MyClass::download(QUrl url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(url);

    QNetworkReply *reply = pManager.get(request);

    // finished() is called after error(), but try both
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(requestError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(requestFinished()));
}

void MyClass::requestError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    qDebug() << "error";
}

void MyClass::requestFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "finished";
}
```

I also connected the access manager like this :

```
connect(&pManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

When the Internet connection is not interrupted, I am going in the slot requestFinished(), but if there's not Internet anymore, I am not entering any slot.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, I was doing it wrong. Since I want to check the internet connection, I have to check the network availability via `QNetworkAccessManager`, by doing this :

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
pManager.setConfiguration(manager.defaultConfiguration());

connect(&pManager, SIGNAL(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)), this, SLOT(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)));
```

And when the Internet breaks down, I will be in the corresponding slot.